# How to mimic groupBy on a collection returned from an Eloquent query?

Tags: laravel

I have a few queries that are almost identical but are different in the `groupBy` clauses.

These are some of the similar queries:

```
MyModel::select(DB::raw('SUM('col1') as col1, SUM('col2') as col2), SUM('col3') as col3'))
    ->groupBy('col1')
    ->get()
```

and

```
MyModel::select(DB::raw('SUM('col1') as col1, SUM('col2') as col2), SUM('col3') as col3'))->groupBy('col1')
    ->groupBy('col2')
    ->get();
```

and

```
MyModel::select(DB::raw('SUM('col1') as col1, SUM('col2') as col2), SUM('col3') as col3'))
    ->groupBy('col1')->groupBy('col2')->groupBy('col3')
    ->get();
```

Now I know that collections have `groupBy` and `sortBy`, but it doesn't work as expected here, since the collection returned from my queries is nested:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
    #items: array: 1 [
        0 => App\Models\MyModel
           #attributes: array // <-- the actual data is here
```

so if I try to use it like in the docs, it won't work:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-groupby

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

I want to have a single "base" query, and on top of this query, do the different `groupBy`'s on the collection so that I only do 1 database query instead of multiple:

```
MyModel::select(DB::raw('SUM('col1') as col1, SUM('col2') as col2), SUM('col3') as col3'))->get()
```

And on top of it do the `groupBy`'s

Is it possible?

Comment: the wanted result doesn't seem obvious here, can you provide a sample data of the wanted outcome ?

Answer (score 0):

You may pass a string to `->groupBy($value)` or a closure

the string needs to be an attribute on the models in the collection which under the hood laravel converts this to a closure `fn ($item) => data_get($item, $value)`

using a closure:

```php
/**
 * @param Model $item
 */
$collection->groupBy(function($item) {
    return $item->{$value}
});
```

you make also pass an array to group by multiple

```php
$collection->groupBy(['col_1', 'col_2'])
```

what this will do is create a collection of collections. first collection being grouped by `col_1` and in each `col_1` collection would be a collection grouped by `col_2` which would be a collection of records

```php
// with the following structure
collect([
    ['col_1' => '1a', 'col_2' => '1b', 'col_3' => '1'],
    ['col_1' => '2a', 'col_2' => '1b', 'col_3' => '2'],
    ['col_1' => '1a', 'col_2' => '2b', 'col_3' => '3'],
    ['col_1' => '2a', 'col_2' => '2b', 'col_3' => '4'],
    ['col_1' => '3a', 'col_2' => '3b', 'col_3' => '5'],
])->groupBy(['col_1', 'col_2']);
```

```php
// you will get:
Illuminate\Support\Collection {
  all: [
    "1a" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#col_1
      all: [
        "1b" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#col_2
          all: [
            [
              "col_1" => "1a",
              "col_2" => "1b",
              "col_3" => "1",
            ],
          ],
        },
        "2b" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#col_2
          all: [
            [
              "col_1" => "1a",
              "col_2" => "2b",
              "col_3" => "3",
            ],
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    "2a" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#col_1
      all: [
        "1b" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#col_2
          all: [
            [
              "col_1" => "2a",
              "col_2" => "1b",
              "col_3" => "2",
            ],
          ],
        },
        "2b" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#col_2
          all: [
            [
              "col_1" => "2a",
              "col_2" => "2b",
              "col_3" => "4",
            ],
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    "3a" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#col_1
      all: [
        "3b" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#col_2
          all: [
            [
              "col_1" => "3a",
              "col_2" => "3b",
              "col_3" => "5",
            ],
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

even though `col_2` has the same value same we first grouped by `col_1` then inside of each collection in `col_1` we grouped by `col_2`

I am not 100% what your question is but i hope this helps you understand more of how it works